# defining heroku rescue workers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, resque

In the heroku rescue tutorial (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque), it says to put the following line in the Procfile.  However, this is for ruby, I'm assuming.

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

Where would I put this line in ruby on rails?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Procfile file in your RoR project. Then add that line of code there.